# SQL 2008: Exclude row if 2 columns in one row has these values

Tags: sql-server-2008

Good Day, for example purposes: with these given data from my query.

```
T0.Date   T0.customer    T0.total   T1.Date,  T1.Total
2.1.2017  BLABLA         2,400.00   3.8.2017  2,400.00
1.2.2017  BLOBLO         5,000.00   3.1.2017  5,000.00
1.1.2017  BLEBLE         3,000.00   2.5.2017  3,000.00
12.5.2016 BLABLA         1,000.00   1.25.2017 1,000.00
```

How can i possibly get the idea of removing rows with T0.Date=January(1) and on the same row that T1.Date=March(3) into a query. I was thinking of using case when inside where clause but i dont know how to begin the condition. But then, if the T1.Date=February(2), doesn't matter if the T0.Date=1 or last years month(12.1.2016)..

**UPDATE:**
Expected output:

```
T0.Date   T0.customer    T0.total   T1.Date, T1.Total
2.1.2017  BLABLA         2,400.00   3.8.2017 2,400.00
1.1.2017  BLEBLE         3,000.00   2.5.2017 3,000.00
12.5.2016 BLABLA         1,000.00   1.25.2017 1,000.00
```

Comment: Question is not clear. Can you please explain it clearly with expected output?

Comment: Something like if the T1.Date is march and up it will not allow T0.Date that is januarry. But if T1.Date is February, it's okay to have T0.Date with january dates and below(2016).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
where T0.Date <> '2017-01-01' or T1.Date <> '2017-03-03'
```

Or, if you are just looking for the entire *month*:

```
where not ( (t0.date >= '2017-01-01' and t0.date < '2017-02-01') and
            (t1.date >= '2017-03-01' and t1.date < '2017-04-01')
          )
```

Comment: Okay i was thinking of using just the month because there will be no particular date. Because this data is created through Date Range so there will be a lot of dates. So my idea is just using MONTH()

Answer (score 0):

This should work...

```
where month(dateadd(month,1,T0_date))=month(T1_date) and year(dateadd(month,1,T0_date))=year(T1_date)
```